# Why won't my CSS classes load?

Tags: html, css, class

My PHP looks like this (it's in a `while` loop) :

```
 print"<li>
   <a class='topcategory' href='index.php?category=$encode'>$category[name]</a>
 </li>";
```

My CSS looks like this:

```
.topcategory {
    display: block;
    float: right;
    height: 20px;
    padding: 10px 20px 0 20px;
    border: none;
    font-size: 85%;
    font-weight: bold;
    color:#333;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-align:center;
}
```

But it doesn't affect my `<a>` tag at all, why?

(later edit) ---> Weird, it seems it spontaneously started working after 10 minutes of just looking on the code and refreshing even though i didn't do anything

Comment: Could you show us the HTML it generates? Where's your CSS defined? In a .css file or as part of the HTML?

Comment: @user Inspect that element in Chrome's developer tools and check which styles are applied and where they're coming from...

Comment: Could you post the html that is generated, because I tried the styling and it works perfectly fine.

Comment: Are you sure your CSS is correctly included and loaded?

Comment: @user783476, whenever you are dealing with javascript or css and refreshing the page constantly, 1) make sure you are not loading cached resources by hitting CTRL+F5 and 2) make sure all of your reference paths and the branch you are working on are correct if you are using a source control mechanism.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not weird at all. It's the browser cache. It is very common with CSS files, so from now on, be sure you check that first.

Answer (score 3):

All my examples assume HTML of...

```
<li>
    <a href="#" class="topcategory">Example</a>
</li>
```

When you are writing your CSS, the order of the style rules matters, so if you have rules like this...

```
.topcategory {
     color: red;
}

a {
    color: blue;
}
```

CSS follows your order and the rule for "a" will override your rule for ".topcategory".

You can solve this in a few ways, but the easiest is to declare rules in order of generality / specificality, so declare your most general rules first, then declare rules in a more specific way later...

In this example, we start by declaring really general tag names, then slightly more specific tag names, then very specific tag names, then class names and finally ids. Using this order means that the cascading nature of CSS will apply the most specific rule to your element.

```
body {
    color: Silver;
}

div {
    color: Orange;
}

p {
    color: Yellow;
}

a {
    color: Blue;
}

.topcategory {
    color: red;
}

.topcategory span {
    color: black;
}

#someid {
    color: Aqua;
}

#someid span {
    color: Green;
}
```

You can override the cascade by using !important - but it is much easier to maintain if you declare your rules in the right order instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
li a.topcategory {
    display: block;
    float: right;
    height: 20px;
    padding: 10px 20px 0 20px;
    border: none;
    font-size: 85%;
    font-weight: bold;
    color:#333;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-align:center;
}
```

If you have defined another rule for `a` tags elsewhere in your CSS, then this rule will overwrite those and force the priority of this class over `a` tags with the class `topcategory`.

Comment: This only makes it so other elements with class `topcategory` won't be affected.

Comment: This is just a stricter rule, the original rule should work as well.

Comment: @Kokos: How do you know he want's to use that class elsewhere, except, an `a` tag?

Comment: @Aston: Yes, a stricter rule, which might work for him, if he has defined another rule for `li a` tag elsewhere. This will overwrite those rules.

Comment: @Shef I don't think you deserve a downvote for this. The order of evaluation of the looser and stricter rules would mean that it's unlikely another rule is overriding this but it's definitely worth the consideration. A useful answer indeed.

Comment: @Shef If you have explained this in your answer, instead of just spitting out a piece of code, maybe you would get less downvotes. The answer is for the OP (and maybe other people with a similar problem), not for those who understand what is going on and upvote.

Comment: @bazmegakapa The definition for a downvote is "This answer is not useful". Any answer with merit (as in this case) does not fit that description. Maybe it's not worthy of an upvote but that doesn't mean it should therefore be downvoted.

Comment: @bazmegakapa: I gave him a solution. If the OP wants to know, he will ask, he will research. I am giving him the cherry, if he wants the cake he should look for it, because that's how he will learn. You can keep down voting, it's your freedom.

Comment: @Brendan The answer was not useful without an explanation.

Comment: @Shef You're doing it backwards :). Give him a solution without an explanation, he will use it and never understand why it works. Give him an explanation without final code, he might learn :). (note: I removed my downvote when you added explanation)

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
print "<li>
   <a class='topcategory' href='index.php?category=".$encode."'>".$category['name']."</a>
 </li>";




<style> 
   .topcategory {
        display: block !important;
        float: right !important;
        height: 20px !important;
        padding: 10px 20px 0 20px !important;
        border: none !important;
        font-size: 85% !important;
        font-weight: bold !important;
        color:#333  !important;
        text-decoration:none !important;
        text-align:center !important;
    }

</style>
```